# How to fetch only one enter from multiple entry

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

My MySQL Database is like this

[image]

I want to have a query which will fetch every element from `car` table, but only one entry (any one) from the `car_picture` table for every car.

So, I want to have a query result like -

[image]

Is it possible?

Thanks in advance for helping.

Comment: It would be better if you posted your schema either as sample table data or `CREATE TABLE` statements, so we could copy them into sqlfiddle for testing. We can't cut and paste from images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `GROUP BY` to get one row per `car_id`.

```
SELECT c.car_id, cp.car_picture_link, c.original_car_page
FROM car AS c
LEFT JOIN car_picture AS cp ON c.car_id = cp.car_id
GROUP BY c.car_id
```

`LEFT JOIN` will return `NULL` for the columns from `car_picture` when there's no corresponding row there.